# How to plot ROC curve for cross validation from Weka output for binary class and multiclass data?

Tags: r, matlab, weka, cross-validation

I have tried different matlab functions like plotroc and packages in R like pROC, ROCR and cvAUC. Each package or function produces different graph and gives different AUC than Weka result.

I would like to compare multiple classifier using 10-fold-cross-validation and would like to pot ROC of each. I have collected results in Weka but I don't want to plot it in Weka itself.

My experiments are based on both binary class and multi-class data.

My Weka output cross-validated instance predictions are at https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0BzRIG3kN-8Z9fnh5OElKTExNT2NuZUVna2tKcmMzU1VBankwdVc2OGxBSXFnaFJqSEhHYVE&usp=sharing

Please, suggest me how can I plot graph for attached results for binaryclass as well as multiclass.

Answer (score 2):

This is a placeholder answer, but the first thing to note is that one your observations got cross-validated less than 10 times:

```
library(pROC)
library(dplyr)

filenameROC = "Data/term3_IBk_3_multiclass.txt"
fileROC = readLines(filenameROC)
dfCV = read.csv2(text = fileROC,
                 nrows = length(fileROC) - 51 - 19,
                header = TRUE, 
                sep = ",",
                skip = 19, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


dfCV %>%
  group_by(inst.) %>%
  tally() %>%
  filter(n < 10)
```

Which gives:

```
> dfCV %>%
+   group_by(inst.) %>%
+   tally() %>%
+   filter( n < 10)
Source: local data frame [1 x 2]

  inst. n
1   773 4
```

Can you explain this?

Additionally, you also need to add a cross-validation iteration identifier. Once you do that it is simply a question of running `multiclass.roc` from the `pROC` package by CV iteration.

### Edit:

OP claims that there are 7724 *observations` whereas it is easy to see that there are 773 observations repeated 10 times in 772 cases and 4 times for observation number 772 -- consistent with 10-fold cross-validation data:

```
> dfCV %>%
+   group_by(inst.) %>%
+   tally()
Source: local data frame [773 x 2]

   inst.  n
1      1 10
2      2 10
3      3 10
4      4 10
5      5 10
6      6 10
7      7 10
8      8 10
9      9 10
10    10 10
..   ... ..
```

### Edit 2:

Here is the code to produce the multi-class ROC by CV fold:

```
dfCVROC = dfCV %>%
  dplyr::filter(inst. != 773) %>%
  arrange(inst.) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(cvfold = rep.int(1:10, 772)) %>%
  group_by(cvfold) %>%
  do(multiclass_roc = multiclass.roc(as.factor(.$actual), as.numeric(.$prediction)))

# get the AUCs by CV fold
sapply(dfCVROC$multiclass_roc, function(x) x$auc)
```

Comment: There are total 7724 observations. I am running 10-fold cross-validation. So in testing set 4 folds are having 773 observations while rest are having 772 observations. The files attached are the output of Weka and as per my knowledge it does not includes iteration number by default. Thanks.

Comment: When I run your code I am getting Error: could not find function "%>%" Am I missing any library?

Comment: @b.bhavesh If you loaded `dplyr` it should have loaded `magrittr`. If not, you can explicitly load `library(magrittr)`.

Comment: @b.bhavesh To me `inst.` looks like it is the observation number, and note that it is repeated 10 times for each observation except observation number 773. Check the extra output above.

Comment: Thanks. I loaded the magrittr and its working now. As I answered above there are total 7724 observations. So 772 observations repeated 10 times and 773 4 times only. It is how Weka divides the data for cross-validation. Should I have to ignore observation number 773 to continue?

Comment: @b.bhavesh Well, it would be easier to work with if we discarded observation 773, and then created the multiclass ROC for each CV fold.

Comment: Thanks again. With this code I get AUC 0.60 to 0.63, which is not equivalent to AUC provided by Weka i.e. 0827. Please check the results at the end of file. Also, how to plot this?

Comment: @b.bhavesh At this point, you need to do a little bit of research to understand what you are looking for. Check the definition of computation of multiclass ROC in the `pROC` package (it gives a specific literature reference), and also what Weka is computing (I don't work with Weka, so I don't know). If you are not sure, then I suggest that you ask at stats.stackexchange, as this is no longer a programming question.

Comment: @b.bhavesh By the way, please note that the `pROC` man page on `multiclass.roc` also tells you that there is no reasonable way to plot multiclass ROCs.

Comment: Thanks. Once again I clear my question. I would like to plot ROC curve for binary class and multiclass cross-fold validation (files attached) to represent my results effectively. So you can consider it as two problems: First, plot cross-validation data as one curve and second plot multiple curve (each for one class). The result of your code gives me 10 AUC (each for different fold). It didn't understand how it will help me.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find exact solution for the issue. However, here are some points that I observe from Weka output

1. While weka plots the ROC it get predictions directly from classifier evaluation output.
2. Weka uses predictions upto 6 decimal points number for calculating threshold values (more precision helps in calculating more number of threshold values for ROC curve).
3. By default in Weka explorer, classifier outputs prediction upto 3 decimal points only (as in my attached experiments results).

Apart from this I didn't understand how Weka calculates the threshold values form the predictions. I observe that with same Weka prediction output I found different threshold values in Weka and R (and Matlab).

Finally, I used Weka API code for plotting ROC [Generate ROC Curve](https://weka.wikispaces.com/Generating+ROC+curve) and extract the TPR and FPR for the experiments (I re-run all the experiments). After extracting TPR and FPR I can plot graphs in any tool like Excel, gnuplot, Matlab or R.

Comment: Can you please advise on how to calculate ROC AUC through rWeka?